# What species is this large bug? (South India)

Tags: species-identification

I found this bug in South India. What species is it? The tiles in the picture are 5x5 centimeters each. The bug was moving relatively slowly and didn't seem to fear me much.

[image]

<sup>I tried asking it directly, but it kept claiming to be a feature.</sup>

Comment: The question has been correclty answered I think but out of curiosity: what do you mean by `I tried asking it directly, but it kept claiming to be a feature.`?

Comment: @Remi.b http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=It%27s%20not%20a%20bug%2C%20it%27s%20a%20feature

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suppose it's a [whip scorpion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thelyphonida).

[image]

> Whip scorpion (order Uropygi, sometimes Thelyphonida), any of approximately 105 species of the arthropod class Arachnida that are similar in appearance to true scorpions except that the larger species have a whiplike telson, or tail, that serves as an organ of touch and has no stinger. The second pair of appendages, the pedipalps, are spiny pincers, and the third pair are long feelers.

It is [most common](https://www.britannica.com/animal/whip-scorpion) in India and Japan to New Guinea.

Comment: In the new picture, why are the mouth-parts different from the specimen in my picture?

Comment: Sorry I made a wrong edit. It happened while rolling back an edit made by another member of the community. I've corrected it now,.